# Table to Table with tab deliminator

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I am trying to create a table from a tab delimited csv. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/GIS/DESIGN/ROW/testWorkspace.py", line 37, in <module>
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(inTable, outLocation, outTable, expression)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 2038, in TableToTable
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Rows: Dataset WO_Export_2014.txt does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (TableToTable).
```

I am new to arpy and I don't get how to use arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters, I believe this may be the issues, but I can't tell where I went wrong.

```
import os

# create an empty list to hold the path to all of your txt files
document_list = []

#  Open a directory and list files
fpath = r"G:\GIS\PUBLIC\ROADS\Work_Order_XY_Export\From_SAP\to_GIS\current_files"
gdbpath = r"G:\GIS\PUBLIC\ROADS\Work_Order_XY_Export\From_SAP\to_GIS\current_files\SAPExport.gdb"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(fpath):
 for name in files:
    # Ensure it is a .txt file before adding to list
    if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(path, name))[1] == ".txt":
        document_list.append(os.path.join(path, name))
    print document_list
# loops through all files
for file in document_list:

    # Import system modules
    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env

    # Set environment settings
    env.workspace = gdbpath

    # Set local variables
    inTable = os.path.basename(file)
    outLocation = gdbpath
    outTable = os.path.basename(file)

    # Set the expression, with help from the AddFieldDelimiters function to select the appropriate field delimiters for the data type
    expression = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(env.workspace, "Work_Order") # "Work_Order" is the first field name. 

    # Execute TableToTable
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(inTable, outLocation, outTable, expression)
```

Comment: Addfielddelimiters is for building sql queries, so will do nothing for importing. Your variable "intable" should actually be "file" from your for loop as you have hardwired the environment workspace to be your geodatabase.

Comment: @Hornbydd my inTable does call back to file.  "inTable = os.path.basename(file)" A little redundant, yes, but it helps me understand the process better.  As for AddFieldDelimiters,I took the code from the ESRI website for table to table. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm.  How would table conversion read tab delimited without it.  Is there some other way?

Comment: Yes but you are taking the BASENAME which would be "xyz.csv", this is not the full path. You are setting the path by your workspace environment setting. You need to set that for your output table but it would be point to a geodatabase which is not the location of your csv files. Soo... you need to be using "file" as your input table.

Comment: Also your code is inefficient, you do not need to keep importing the arcpy module or setting the workspace _within_ the for loop and get rid of the addfielddeliminters line as that is not doing anything.

Comment: I think that you are showing us far more than the [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) needed to try and reproduce (and then debug) your 000732 error.  What happens when you test just the TableToTable line with the four variables used in it printed beforehand (so you can be certain of their values)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issues with your code:

- you might be printing too many times `print document_list` - you might like printing just once after your have gone through all the files;
- unfortunate naming of the csv file variable as `file` - it's one of the [built-in Python objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642087/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-keywords-in-python) which you would like to avoid using for naming variables. Let's use `csv_file` further in the code.
- `outTable` variable will be `nameoffile.txt`. You cannot use dots in a geodatabase table name. You could remove the extension using `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv_file))[0]`
- `inTable` variable will be referring to `nameoffile.txt`. However, when you run your code, the Python module file is not stored in the folder with the text file, so Python won't find it which is why are you getting this error you posted. You have to provide the full path to the file. This means you don't need the `inTable` variable as your `csv_file` variable will already have the whole path.
- `expression` is not a valid SQL expression. You need to build a where clause using both the field and the value such as

`sql_exp = """ {0} = '{1}' """.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(env.workspace, "Work_Order"), 'Order55')`

When you are done with that, running your code will likely result in another error:

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000339: Input grafiti.csv does not
>   have OIDs Failed to execute (TableToTable).

if your text file doesn't have a valid OID field. This can be fixed by first copying the text file into a scratch table (essentially adding OID field) and then using this in-memory table to do the `Table To Table`. You cannot use a where clause with the `Copy Rows`.

`in_memory_table = arcpy.CopyRows_management(in_rows=csv_file, out_table=r"in_memory\tbl")`

- it's best to put all your imports to the top of the module so you can see what dependencies your code has.

#### Complete code:

```
import os
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# create an empty list to hold the path to all of your txt files
document_list = []

#  Open a directory and list files
fpath = r"C:\GIS\Temp"
gdbpath = r"C:\GIS\Temp\ArcGISHomeFolder\Default.gdb"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(fpath):
    for name in files:
        # Ensure it is a .txt file before adding to list
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(path, name))[1] == ".csv":
            document_list.append(os.path.join(path, name))

print document_list

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = gdbpath

# Set local variables
outLocation = gdbpath

# loops through all files
for csv_file in document_list:
    outTable = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv_file))[0]

    # Set the expression, with help from the AddFieldDelimiters function to select the appropriate field delimiters for the data type
    expression = "{0} > {1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(r'in_memory', "SqFtAprox"), 7)

    # Execute TableToTable
    in_memory_table = arcpy.CopyRows_management(in_rows=csv_file, out_table=r"in_memory\tbl")
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(in_memory_table, outLocation, outTable, expression)
```

Comment: Thank you, you were very thorough.  I received a trackback error on in_memory table and got this error rcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 001156: Failed on input OID -1, could not write value '000040103719... this entry is a row in the middle of one of my files.  I easily have 10 thousand rows is this just too much for in memory?

Comment: I found the issue it was inconstancy in the data, thanks again for your help.